# Deleted comment tab and notification

Tags: feature-request, comment, deletion, notifications

After a few months on this website, I have had a few of my comments deleted. As it happens, I agree with the deletions in all of those cases. However, there was no notification that they were deleted, and I only found out by revisiting the questions to find the comments weren't there. More importantly (as far as I can tell) there is no way to view your previously deleted comments. Therefore if I were to have a dispute with a deletion of a comment I made, I would only be able to make a post on meta from my memory.

I therefore am putting forward a feature request that a deleted comments section be implemented into profile tabs (when you click "all actions" perhaps there could be a tick-box to include deleted comments). This could be perhaps for a limited amount of time such as 30 days so as not to create unnecessary clutter (though I have no idea how such things work so maybe this wouldn't be required). I would also like to request a notification when your comment gets deleted.

I feel such a feature is necessary for there to be more transparency in the moderation process, and also so that we know whenever a comment we made has been deleted. If the notification would include the reasoning, then it would assist in preventing future occurences of such comments.

Thoughts?

Comment: "If the notification would include the reasoning, then it would assist in preventing future occurences of such comments." Sometimes comments which were perfectly fine at the time when they were made become obsolete due to later events, and get deleted. Notification including reasoning would do nothing to prevent further occurences of such comments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is true, but there are plenty of examples where it would prevent further occurrences e.g. if the comment was too chatty. Additionally, I personally would like to be informed if a comment of mine has been deleted due to it having become obsolete.